# How To Calculate Drop Off Rates

Tags: statistics

Been a long time since I've had to delve into statistical maths. I'm trying to work out the correct way to monitor drop off rates.

Say I have a series of percentages, with each one representing a day. e.g.

100, 100, 95, 100, 55, 53, 44, 92, 100, 95, 98, 100, 100, 95, 100

At each point within the above series I need a way to monitor what the current trend is and the current rate of change to the norm.

So far I've been working out the current mean at each position but not too sure on what the correct approach to go from here is.

Comment: you could try a mean of say, five consecutive days, and see how that changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For trends **moving averages** are the way to go. So each day you calculate the average of the last $n$ days. $n$ might be 7 or 30. Whatever you find most useful. In the sample data you gave, there was a serious drop on days 5,6,7. If you make $n$ too large, such drops will hardly register. You probably want to show both the daily rate and a moving average.

You also need to plot the results. In practice, that probably means setting it up in a spreadsheet. If you have some kind of target you could also show that on the graph.

You don't give the context. If it is in relation to web pages, you should also check out Google Analytics.

Comment: Makes perfect sense. Thanks.